# How can I send an email to a google contact group on my iOS devices?

Tags: ios, contacts, gmail

I have groups in my Google Contacts for sending emails to sets of people via the web interface on a browser.

I sync Google mail and contacts onto a couple iOS devices via Microsoft Exchange.

How can I send an email to a google group from iOS? Neither the built in mail/contact apps have any reference to my groups, and I cannot acces them via the web browser (mobile version), nor the official gmail app (which seems to be a resigned web interface).

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, there's not a way of doing it with the native iOS app. Try using the Gmail app (which I personally prefer). If not, there's this little workaround: http://red66.com/2009/07/how-to-send-group-emails-from-your-iphone/

The gist of the workaround is to make one contact for the group and add a comma separated list of emails to the singular email field for the "group contact"

This doesn't allow you to leverage arbitrary groups and does require some manual setup, but once that's done you can email limited group sizes from iOS without needing a computer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thanks for posting an answer!! Cam you please summarize the content of the link you posted? Links have a tendency to disappear over time, leaving an answer that isn't helpful for those who may find it later. Thanks!

Comment: My question mentions already trying the Gmail app. The work around you link to is quite horrid.

Comment: Yep, but it looks like it's the only option that exists ;)

Answer (score 2):

I use Google Chrome on iOS.

Go to google.com/contacts and choose "Request Desktop Site" from the top right icon (three horizontal lines).

Select your group from the left and click the empty square above the list to select all members.  It will then open a new message in Gmail to all the recipients.

I've tested this on my iPad, running iOS 6

Comment: Works with Safari and iOS 13.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is possible, I just went into my sent mail where I've emailed 34 people from my desktop, I clicked forward email, which will display all of the emails, I selected all, copied. Went to contacts on my ipad mini, created a name called grouped apples for example, clicked on email, and pasted all 34 email addresses, click done. Go to gmail app in apple os ipad, click compose, click plus sign, select name in contacts where group emails were added, and click send once email is ready. It sent. I know it did because I received 13 out of office replies. I did get a message that said invalid email, send anyway? I selected send and it sent to everyone

Comment: This is a great workaround. Will be a big help in the future.

Comment: Grabbing all emails from a previously sent or forwarded email in a single copy operation is much better then selecting contacts to copy one by one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the app "ContactSync" to turn your Google Groups into mail groups for the ios mail.

Comment: Since that term matches quite a large several handfuls of apps on the iOS app store, would you possibly link to the specific app you found that enables this functionality?

Comment: This one: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/contacts-sync-for-google-gmail/id454390333

Answer (score 1):

I run a list (upwards of 300 names) and have been stymied by this as well when needing to send an email on the run ("Hey--we're still playing disc today...")

My work around is to save a draft letter (from the web app) with the BCC filled in with my group members.  I just leave the letter sitting in "Drafts".  Then when I need to send a quick email using my iPhone, I use that draft, and change the body and subject.

drawbacks:
 1) Have to remember to make a new draft next time I'm on a a desktop.
 2) The names are not dynamic, so all changes to the group are not reflected in the draft BCC (additions or deletions to the group)

Hope this is resolved sooner than later!

Answer (score 0):

## [Groups](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/groups-sms-mail-manage-contacts/id300891442?mt=8)

- send group SMS and Email to any group (including Exchange servers or Google Sync)
- mail groups with To, Cc and Bcc selections
- drag&drop single or multiple contacts into or out of groups
- vCard attachments
- merge contacts
- built-in T9 Dial
- ...

[image]

Comment: Feel free to list the feature where I can send to a Google contact group...

Comment: @mindless.panda No problem.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, the Google Chrome method above doesn't work if the Group is too large because the URL is too long.  (My group is 46 emails.)

I found that the best method is to simply create a draft email on my desktop and then write and send from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered I could go to https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
On my iPad within Safari to get to a clone of my desktop PC Gmail app.  I can compose an email and select one of my Groups to send it.

The Gmail app from the app store does not have this feature.  The cumbersome workarounds above are not needed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.

Comment: How does this differ from the answer by JL78 - if just using Safari rather than Chrome then given the comments on that answer this should be an edit

Comment: It is similar.  I used Safari and The “Request Desktop Site” option was not there for me.  It does not work on my iPhone though.

As a new contributor, I am not allowed to add a comment to JL78’s post.