# How do I send a group email on my iPad Air?

Tags: ios, mail.app, contacts

I'm having trouble sending email to a group from my iPad (with the email app that came with the iPad).

The groups are there under my contact groups. I open a new email, click on the "to" field, and then click the "+" button, click "groups", click on the group that I want so that there is a check mark next to it, press "done", click back to the email, and then the "to" field is still empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you looking to have one mail go to a large group like this? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45255/how-can-i-send-an-email-to-a-google-contact-group-on-my-ios-devices or something else?

Comment: Originally that was my problem, but I solved it via the app ContactSync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tick mark doesn't mean that you've added them to the To field — it just means that you've narrowed down the list of contacts to that group.

When you tap the **+** button to add to the To field, by default it shows All Contacts. Pressing Groups lets you narrow down this list to that specific group, but you still need to select the people that you want to send the email to. Tap them in the list (and select their email if necessary) to add them to the To field.

Comment: Wait, so I just tap each individual person in the Group? I have to go through my entire address book and find each person?  I'm confused about the narrowing. I need a step-by-step. I have a group entitled "precalculus". I open a new email. I want to send that email to the "precalculus" group. So I go to the "To" field and then press the "+". Then what?

Comment: @Alison Indeed, when you open the 'add contact' view, it shows all the contacts by default, *but by selecting a group it reduces this list to only show people in that group*. You still need to tap each person to add them. For your example, you tap the **+**, then Groups, then the group so that the precalculus group is the only one with a tick, then Done. The list will then only show people in that group. Tap each one to add them to the To field.

Comment: Ok. I see. But this is slightly annoying of course. I can't just, after selecting the Precalculus group, go to the contacts and just automatically add all from that list?

Comment: @Alison Nope — as a workaround, create a contact called Precalculus, and add a comma-separated list of email addresses to a single email address field, then select that contact.

Comment: @Alison Your disappointment is common to many - adding a group in one tap isn't supported by iOS. The iOS 7 note indicates "Choose a contact to mail" even when you have narrowed the contact list to just one group of people.